# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I am currently building an Automatic licence plate recongition system. I am referring to this page

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/kislayabhi/89b985e5b78a6f56029a

In this code, two paramters namely "**CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE and CV_FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY"** are used.

It has been called in the program by using cv2.cv as **cv2.cv.CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE**

But when I tried executing the program, I got an error stating that **cv2 has no attribute named cv**

I also tried changing it to cv2.CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE as in Opencv3 the version changes cv has been deprecated

But I get the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE'
```

This means that either I have called CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE wrong or it is not available in the name called

Can anyone please tell me what should I do for solving this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help to show a small fragment of your code that illustrates the problem. How did you install cv2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the version of cv2 in the notebook was built, but I suspect it might not have come out of the standard python package index. The notebook code 
refers to `cv2.cv.CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE`, but `opencv-python` 3.4.3 (the current version in the package index) doesn't provide `cv2.cv`.

The underling C++ definitions (see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/73bfe688219235e6a62cd1ef0cc19fd0cc656df2/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h#L627)) are

```
CV_FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE =(1 << 16),
CV_FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY   =(1 << 17)
```

so you might try the equivalent ints in your python code in place of the `CV_FLOODFILL_*` constants.